# reading value from XML?

Tags: c#, xml

The XML data:

```
<LIST>
  <TITLE>Item</TITLE>
  <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
  <NAME>
    <NAME_ n="1">AB</NAME_>
    <NAME_ n="2">CD</NAME_>
    <NAME_ n="3">EF</NAME_>
    <NAME_ n="4">GH</NAME_>
    <NAME_ n="5">IJ</NAME_>
  </NAME>
  <PRICE>
    <PRICE_ n="1">100</PRICE_>
    <PRICE_ n="2">103</PRICE_>
  </PRICE>
  <AV>
    <AV_ n="0">128,457</AV_>
    <AV_ n="1">1,746,301</AV_>
    <AV_ n="2">173,247</AV_>
    <AV_ n="3">246,102</AV_>
  </AV>
  <PIC>
    www.example.com/pictest.jpg
  </PIC>
  <URL>www.test.com/itemtest</URL>
</LIST>
```

I tried with this code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(a);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Name == "AV")
    {
        label1.Text += reader.Value;
    }
```

Now, I know that I need more help with my code since I can't get any output!
How can I read values from this XML?

Anyone can help me for get **all value** from this XML ? bcs I'm very very new in xml and need for sample for start work ! :(

Comment: Any reason you want to use `XmlTextReader`? Can you just load it into an `XDocument`? It would be a lot simpler...

Comment: I'm very new in XML i don't know how can i use from 'XDocument' can you give me sample or somthing for this XML ?

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant to have space after "_".

Comment: @ John Saunders : i try for copy and past XML for code But i can't! know can you please help me ?:(

Comment: Code and XML needs to be indented by 4. After you paste it, select it, and click the "{}" button in the toolbar.

Comment: @John Saunders : OPS ! , I'm new in this site :D , Thanks for edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding the parent element and getting the text value of it. It doesn't have a text value, only another child.

Try instead

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(a);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "AV_")
            {
                label1.Text += reader.Value;
            }
```

Comment: i need for more help for get all value ! can you help more ?

Answer (score 1):

To get all numeric values and attribute number from contents of `AV_` node, use next script:

```
string str = "..."; //xml contents go here

var xml = XDocument.Parse(str);

var values = xml.Descendants("AV_")
                .Select(n => n.Attribute("n").Value + " : " + n.Value);


values.ToList()
      .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

prints:

```
0 : 128,457
1 : 1,746,301
2 : 173,247
3 : 246,102
```

don't forget to add reference to Linq to XML namespace `using System.Xml.Linq`